# How do I properly reference external Excel files to copy and paste specified values based on matching dates?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have two excel files. One is named "Flow Levels" while the other is called "Rainfall NOAA". The purposed of the Flow Levels file is to graph the relationship between flow levels in sewers across NYC and the rainfall associated in that area. The flow level values are obtained from a separate website and are already in the Flow Levels file. The rainfall values are obtained from the "Rainfall NOAA" file. Now, previously, I would just manually type in the Rainfall values from a PDF file located on the NOAA website. Recently, however, I learned about the "Index" and "match" functions that can automatically fill in the Rainfall values based on matching date and time if formatted correctly. This saved a lot of time for me. I need to do this for multiple data sheets (30 in total), so I used this formula repetitively to streamline the process. The issue is, however, whenever I drag down this formula to new data (with new dates), it constantly asks for the source of Rainfall, which I found annoying. So, I used the "Indirect" function to reference the filepath of the "Rainfall NOAA" file so it doesn't have to constantly ask for the file. The formula can be seen here:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $J$4 & "[RainfallNOAA.xlsx]JFK'!B:B"), MATCH(TEXT(A2018,"m/d/yyyy h:mm"),INDIRECT("'" & $J$4 & "[RainfallNOAA.xlsx]JFK'!A:A"),0))),"",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $J$4 & "[RainfallNOAA.xlsx]JFK'!B:B"), MATCH(TEXT(A2018,"m/d/yyyy h:mm"),INDIRECT("'" & $J$4 & "[RainfallNOAA.xlsx]JFK'!A:A"),0)))`

The filepath is stored in cell J4 of the Rainfall NOAA file. I want to reference the specified workbook and the rainfall data in sheet "JFK" (date and time found in col A, Rainfall values in col B). The formula matches the date and time (col A) in m/d/yyyy h:mm format and returns the associated Rainfall values in col B to the Flow Level file. The formula worked previously when omitting the "Indirect" function. But now since I added it, it returns blank cells and gives me invalid cell reference error. What am I missing here to make this work?

Comment: Note that this approach only works if the external file is open.

Comment: Rather than the INDIRECT route, have you tried using a Table so that your formula references are internal table references like:  @[Date]?  This may help with the file 'drag down' issue, but I'd need more information to be sure.  Alternatively, would PowerQuery be a worthwhile endeavor?